# Counting Int Occurrences in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, find-occurrences

I am trying to count the occurrences of integers in an array. I was able to get it to work by piecing together some code I found online but I don't really understand why its working. What I have is:

```
int[] hand = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4};
int[] numOccurence = new int[hand.length];


    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
        numOccurence[hand[i]]++;

    for (int i = 1; i < numOccurence.length; i++)
        if (numOccurence[i] > 0)
            System.out.println("The number " + i + " occurs " + numOccurence[i] + " times.");
```

The output is:
The number 2 occurs 2 times.
The number 3 occurs 1 times.
The number 4 occurs 2 times.

How is this code counting the number of occurrences properly? I don't see how its accomplishing this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are u getting correct output with bigger numbers say `{100, 200, 300, 400}`??

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what it is doing before asking? It is pretty clear how it is counting.

Comment: I dont know why are you testing this program.User just expects an explanation on output.

Answer (score 3):

This is only working because you've a good luck. Try making the second element in the hand array as `5` and see what happens. Its because the number present at the current index of `hand` is taken as the index of array `numOccurence`. In case of a number greater than or equal to the length of the `numOccurence`, you'll get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Thereforce, you can better use a `Map` for this where the key would be the number and the value could be its count.

Something like this:-

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numOccurence = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
    int cnt = 1;
    if (numOccurence.containsKey(hand[i])) {
        cnt = numOccurence.get(hand[i]);
        cnt++;
    }
    numOccurence.put(hand[i], cnt);
}
```

Comment: I dont know why are you testing this program.User just expects an explanation on output.

Answer (score 3):

This code does not really work. At least it does for the author's use case but probably not for yours.

Try with `{2, 4, 99, 2, 4};` as `hand` and it will fail.

The author takes the number found in `hand` as the index of array `numOccurence`. 
`numOccurence` has the following structure : {nb occ of **0**; nb occs of **1**;...; nb occs of **4**}. Here 99 will be out of bounds.

Comment: I dont know why are you testing this program.User just expects an explanation on output.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array

```
int[] numOccurence = new int[hand.length];
```

it is populated by their default values. For primitive int this value is 0.

This will of course only work if hand contains numbers less than or equal to max index (length -1) of the array otherwise it's ArrayIndexOutOfBound for you mister!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's the same method for creating histogram for picture ;)

You create a table where you will gather the occurrence.
 numOccurence[0] will stock the number of 0
 numOccurence[1] will stock the number of 1
etc.

That's what is done by this

```
for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
    numOccurence[hand[i]]++;
```

it adds 1 to the value in the case corresponding to the number hand[i]

so if you look at this step by step
first he will take hand[0] = 2 
so he will put

```
numOccurence[2] = numOccurence[2] + 1 ;
```

which is same (but faster to write) as

```
numOccurence[2]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of performing a count is called [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

The advantage of counting sort is it's speed. The disadvantage is the memory requirements when sorting big numbers.

There is a bug in the code:

```
int[] numOccurence = new int[hand.length];
```

`numOccurence` needs to be as long as the highest number in the list (not the number of numbers in the list). Try changing one of the numbers to `15` and you will get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code is wrong. You should set the size of `numOccurence` array to the max number value from `hand` array + 1. For example:

```
int[] hand = {2, 100};
int[] numOccurence[] = new int[101];
```

(you should obviously find max number programatically)

Now let's take a look at the algorithm.
It takes each number from `hand` array, treats it as a `numOccurence` index value and increments number at that index by 1 in `hand` array. Note that all elements of `numOccurence` array are `0` by default at the beginning.

```
int[] hand = {2, 4, 3, 2, 4};
int[] numOccurence = new int[5];
```

Steps:

`i = 0` (nothing happens, because there is no 0 in `hand` array)

`i = 1` (same situation as for 0)

`i = 2` (there are two `2` numbers in `hand` array, so we do operation `numOccurence[2] += 1` twice, which in result gives 0 + 1 + 1 = 2. So we got `numOccurence[2] = 2`)

it continues for all numbers from `0` to max number from `hand` array (here: `100`).

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates through the given array `hand`. it takes each value encountered as an index into the array `numOccurrence`. for each number `n` in `hand`, this will happen exactly as often as `n` occurs in `hand`, and each time this happens, the `n`th element of `numOccurrence` will be incremented.

thus `numOccurrence` is effectively an array of counters (assuming that the array elements are initialized with `0`).

drawbacks of this approach:

- the number of counters allocated depends on the magnitude of numbers in your `hand`array.
- if the numbers in your `hand` array are distributed sparsely, most of the allocated space is never used.

### alternative

you could improve the code by sorting `hands` first. in the sorted array the indexes of all occurrences of a given number are contiguous, so you scan the sorted array once needing a single counter only to compile the frequencies.